# Como puedo sumar un numero a una fecha? Angular

Tags: angular, date

tengo que sumar un numero a una fecha que obtengo por una consulta

aqui despues de hacer la consulta obtengo la fecha que es "2021-09-27"

```
this.infproductex.fecha_circ = this.inftoexcepcion[0].fecha_circ;
```

y despues en un input solicito un numero ejemplo "2" y lo guardo en la variable `this.nuevoperiodo`
y al darle click al boton quiero que me sume `this.nuevafecha = this.infproductex.fecha_circ + this.nuevoperiodo`

agrego:

`console.log('fecha obtenida '+ this.infproductex.fecha_circ);`

`console.log('nuevo periodo ' +this.nuevoperdiodoex);`

`console.log(this.nuevafecha);`

y obtengo esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedo sumarlo?

Answer (score 1):

Puedes ayudarte del objeto `Date`. Asumiendo que la cantidad que quieres sumarle está en meses, puedes usar el método `getMonth()` y `setMonth()`.

```
let testDate = new Date(this.inftoexcepcion[0].fecha_circ);
testDate.setMonth(testDate.getMonth() + this.nuevoperiodo);
this.nuevafecha = testDate.toLocaleString();
```

Comment: y para poder sumarle dias y no meses como podria quedar?

Answer (score 0):

Pude resolverlo con Moment

```
let fecha = this.inftoexcepcion[0].fecha_circ
    let pp = moment(fecha).add(this.nuevoperdiodo, 'days');
    let aa = moment(pp, "DD/MM/YYYY").format('YYYY-MM-DD');
```